# Problem with using duplicated class in TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity, android-tabhost

I'm having some problem using a ListActivity inside a TabHost. I only want to use one class to show different lists (which I manage), but the problem is that when I click on a new tab, the list doesn't get updated/populated. I found one way to solve it, and that was to create duplicated classes (Listclass1.java, Listclass2.java...). Really not great coding practice.

Here is some of my tabhost code:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListCreator.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", "abilities");       
        this.addTab("", R.drawable.abilities, intent);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListCreator.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", "map"); 
        this.addTab("", R.drawable.map_rules, intent);
```

And here is the Listclass:

```
package no.heroclix.rules;

import heroclix.Rules.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListCreator extends ListActivity {

    private String NAME;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        NAME = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
        Log.d("List", NAME);

        final String[] rules;
        if(NAME.equals("abilities")) rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abilities_names);
        else if(NAME.equals("map")) rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.map_rules_names);
        else if(NAME.equals("objects")) rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.objects_names);
        else if(NAME.equals("ata")) rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ata_names);
        else if(NAME.equals("feats")) rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.feats_names);
        else rules = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bfc_names);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow, rules));
        ListView lw = getListView();
        lw.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListInfo.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("NAME", NAME);
                myIntent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                myIntent.putExtra("SIZE", rules.length);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Any clues?

Edit: I should mention that this worked for a while (not using duplicated classes), but after I did some change (that I have removed) it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Are your ListActivity1,2... only used to wrap ListViews? Why don't you just declare the ListViews in the same activity as the TabHost and switch between them? (The tabs can switch between views as well as activities)

Comment: Not sure how to do that? Do I need to override the tabChange method and do something with the lists there? I also have some tabs who are only activities (without lists), but guess I could always code around those.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't really need to extend ListActivity, and you're trying to do something partially like [Is it realizable on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747834/is-it-realizable-on-android/5750168#5750168)

Answer (score 0):

How about [TabHost.OnTabChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html)?

"Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when tab changed". You could use that to update the tabs upon switching between them.

Comment: I have tried that, but how can I update another class? As the tab is in the Main.java and the lists are in ListActivity.java. This would of course be doable if I where using Views. So maybe I should try that out.

Comment: Okay, I tried this solution. Sadly, I couldn't get it to work, and it looks like there is a lot of work to be done if I should be able to use this solution. As I have other tabs not using a list.