# need help for calling Listactivity from the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, call, listactivity

I need help to know, how can I call ListActivity from the Activity class? Can anyone help me?

Comment: same as you call Activity from other Activity Class... Using StartActivity(Intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "call ListActivity from the Activity class".

If you're looking for information on using ListActivity and/or ListViews, take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html and [Is it realizable on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747834) for examples.

If you're looking for information on starting a ListActivity from another Activity, for example when a button on the non-ListView activity is pressed, note that this isn't much different from just starting a second Activity from some other Activity.  See http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html for such an example.

The notepad tutorial also includes an example of a ListActivity starting a non-ListView Activity, which is very close to what you may be originally asking about.

If you're still stuck, try to ask a very specific question about what you're stuck on, including complete minimal code to replicate any problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include in the Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MyListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```